# Automating "npm install && bower install --dev" with generator-angular for Yeoman

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I am trying to figure out how to automate `npm install && bower install --dev` at the end of the generation of the angular scaffold from the angular generator for Yeoman, and have not found any information that quite matches my problem.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this and it will install npm and bower deps right after finishing scaffolding:

`yo angular && npm install && bower install --dev`

You could also create a shell alias in your `.bashrc`,`.bashprofile`,`.zshrc` file:

`alias ya='yo angular && npm install && bower install --dev'`

Then just restart your Terminal and type `ya`.

Comment: If you want to make it generic, you could also define a function like ```y() {
  yo $1 && (npm install & bower install --dev)
}```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question, but I could use some clarification - is there a problem with automating those commands after Yeoman finishes generating the scaffold from within the generator where doing so is undesirable for any particular reason (or just unfeasible)?

Comment: BahamutWC: We tried that before and it hides away the action for the user, which results in us getting bug reports for every misconfigured system and npm bug, since users naively think it's our bug. Having the user type those commands is also consistent with if you were to clone an already generated project, which you would then have to install the dependencies manually too. The trick @passy showed above is a good way to automate it if you don't want to type them every time, but at least you're aware what's happening and don't blame us :)